# Did NASA have black doctors around 1960?

Tags: nasa, history, project-mercury

In the [2020 TV series "The Right Stuff"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7423322/) a lot of changes are made for dramatic effect. The show has a black doctor working at NASA during the Mercury programme, and he seems to be pretty high ranking too.

Were there any black medical doctors at NASA at that time?

Comment: I can't find a definitive answer, but it's plausible. More government jobs were being opened to African-Americans during the Kennedy administration. US armed forces were integrated starting in 1948; it would be likely that a black NASA doctor in that period would have come from the military.

Comment: Many of the medical personnel involved in the Mercury program did not work for NASA. Many/most worked for the Lovelace Clinic in Albuquerque, NM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The show has a black doctor working at NASA during the Mercury programme, and he seems to be pretty high ranking too.

My initial searches didn't turn up any clues, but there was a [recap of the episode on CollectSpace](http://www.collectspace.com/news/news-111320a-natgeo-right-stuff-episode-recap-ziggurat.html) that mentioned that the black doctor in episode 7 is a real person.

[Colonel Vance Marchbanks](http://www.madehow.com/inventorbios/39/Vance-H-Marchbanks.html) (portrayed by actor Christopher Mann) was one of the first black flight surgeons in the Army and the first in the Air Force. He got an MD from [Howard University](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_University) and joined the USAF in 1941, and was assigned to Project Mercury in 1960.

Comment: `+1` for space detective work!

Comment: [HBCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historically_black_colleges_and_universities) reference added, feel free to edit further.